# How to show all properties of an object in HTML in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

```
  {
    title: "My Title",
    entryID: 1,
    url: "#",
    author: "William Pears, Andrew Cutcher",
    comment_count: 2
  }
```

I got this object and I am trying to figure out how to display this in my React component.

I want to display like a blog entry where when clicking on title I could hopen the link (url) and show author also on the blog entry..

Please help!!

Comment: please paste a react code where you want to display this object

Comment: This question reads as "I have this object, please write my application to do everything I want without me trying anything"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Bernard! Please include the code your have written so far, so we can understand what issue you are having, and so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here:

- where will you store the data?

  - is it in state?

    - then use this.state.{propertyName}

      - @dotnetdev4president explained how to access this.state.property, except, you should wrap the reference in curly braces
  - is it in a constant?

    - then check my example below with JavaScript’s .map method
- for rendering/displaying the data to React Components

  - you might want to check this for blog-like entries: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/card/

Loop through your object, with the above mentioned .map like so:

```
const yourExampleDataConstant = {
  title: "My Title",
  entryID: 1,
  url: "#",
  author: "William Pears, Andrew Cutcher",
  comment_count: 2
};

return <div>
  {yourExampleDataConstant.map(element => (
    return <ul key={element.entryID} >
      <a href={element.url}><li>{element.title}</li></a>
      <li>{element.author}</li>
      <li>{element.comment_count}</li>
    </ul>
  ))}
</div>;
```

}

However, context of your code would be useful!

Hope this helps!

PS.
Looks while I was writing an answer, @nikhilkarkra already replied with what I had in mind :)

Comment: thank youu!! exactly what I needed!!! Reactstrap looks very awesome too, thank you Scott

Answer (score 3):

Map overs the keys of object

`{Object.keys(yourObject).map(function(key) { return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {yourObject[key]}</div>; })}`

Answer (score -1):

If you saved your data into the state with this.setState({your_object}) you can output easyly in jsx:

```
<p>this.state.title</p>
<p>this.state.author</p>
```

And so on...